# Replace + Sign by Underscore

Tags: regular-expressions, replaceall

Trying to replace a character '+' with underscore.
Tried:

```
String s = 'Happy+Me';
System.debug(s.replaceAll('\\+', '_');
System.debug(s.replaceAll('/\[+]', '_');
```

Still gives me 'Happy+Me' result. Well it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: N.B. re: sfdcfox's answer: Option 1 works on strings longer than 1MB; option 2 will throw an uncatchable regex too complicated error if used on strings > 1 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not close bracket. use this below code

```
 String s = 'Happy+Me';
 System.debug(s.replaceAll('\\+', '_'));
```

Comment: Oops sorry about that, Im just typing my code while asking, not copying and pasting it.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

Use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`:

```
System.debug(s.replace('+','_'));
```

## Option 2

Use the appropriate regular expression for `replaceAll`. Note that regular expressions use `\` to escape, but Apex **also** uses `\` to escape. This means you need to use twice as many `\` to get the correct result:

```
System.debug(s.replaceAll('\\+','_'));
```

---

To match a literal `\` in a regular expression string, you would need to use four `\` total:

```
System.debug('Hello\\World'.replace('\\\\',' '));
```

If you're using a Custom Label or other source for your regular expression string, you would not need to escape the `\`, as this only applies during the compilation of Apex code.